# Firebase avoid same node override/updated by multiple clients (web)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

i am using firebase to make checkout system where multiple users of same store can override/update a node at same time.

Scenario/Steps:

User1: Enter item code in system (and he can enter multiple)

User2: Enter item code in system (//)

User3: Release that item code from system

User4 ... and so on.

Code:

```
"-KhBgsi8HwT5BloV0Srt" : {
        "lastUpdated" : 1504285854767,
        "methodName" : "ITEM_ENTERED",
        "payLoad": "{'Id':1, 'ItemName': 'Apples'}"   
      }
```

In above code, whenever any user enters i override above node with methodeName and payLoad of item. ANd whenever user releases item from the system I again update same node by overriding like that:

```
"-KhBgsi8HwT5BloV0Srt" : {
            "lastUpdated" : 1504285854767,
            "methodName" : "ITEM_RELEASED",
            "payLoad": "{'Id':1, 'ItemName': 'Apples'}"   
          }
```

All users are connected to same firebase node which can be override by above users at same time. So if all users do operation at same time the node gets the last one saved in the node. How can i avoid that and make sure all users get same data not the last one happened on node.

At some time when everything is happening quickly by users then above node gets mixed up with ITEM_ENTERED/ITEM_RELEASED methods and clients get out of sync.

I hope i made my point clear. I just need a right direction to fix this concurrency writes to same node.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: But your question doesn't give details on which update should be applied in case two users write to the same node

Comment: Each user when writes to above node it updates payload/methodname/lastupdated of above firebase node.

Comment: @Mocas I want to make sure every action/nodeupdated data be received to all connected devices without any skipping.

Comment: Then rather keeping one node that gets updated by everyone, just push another node

Comment: @Mocas If I push another node how can i make sure all users are seeing latest data. Read all json nodes instead of just one? right?

Comment: When you push another node, the node will be last by default, when reading the reference, you can limit to last one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are getting long, but this seems to be a valid solution to your problem
Just push another node, and make your listener returns the last pushed node

Rather than using child_changed, use child_added

Comment: I am getting your point but currently i am listening to child_changed event if i do above approach adding node each time then should i use orderby with child_added event?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Sorry, another update, I think this would be a better solution